# CarrierWave: Create the same, unique filename for all versioned files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, filenames, carrierwave

Before I go into detail I'll get right to the point: has anyone figured out a way to get Carrierwave to save files with their names as a timestamp or any arbitrary string that is unique to each file?

By default Carrierwave saves each file and its alternate versions in its own directory (named after the model ID number). I'm not a fan of this because instead of one directory with 1,000, for the sake of using a large round number, files (in my case pictures) in it we get one directory with 1,000 subdirectories each with one or two files. Yuck.

Now, when you override your Uploader's `store_dir` method to be something like the following:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}"
end
```

you end up with the exact behavior that I want. All the files (pictures) go into one big happy folder. No more subfolders that stick around when the object gets deleted.

There's only one problem. File collisions. If you upload delicious_cake.jpg twice the second one will overwrite the first even if they are two different pictures of delicious cake! That's clearly why the `store_dir` method has the extra `/#{model.id}` tacked on the end of the value it returns.

So, what to do? After reading around a bit I discovered that in the generated uploader file there is an apparent solution commented out.

```
# Override the filename of the uploaded files:
# Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
# def filename
#   "something.jpg" if original_filename
# end
```

After a little bit of searching I found someone who had done the following

```
def filename
  @name ||= "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename
end
```

This got me thinking, why not just do this

```
def filename
  @name ||= "#{(Time.now.to_i.to_s + Time.now.usec.to_s).ljust(16, '0')}#{File.extname(original_filename)}"
end
```

That's when things got horribly broken. The problem with this is that `filename` apparently gets called for each version of the file so we end up with file names like 1312335603175322.jpg and thumb_1312335603195323.jpg. Notice the slight difference? Each file name is based on the time when `filename` was called for that particular version. That won't do at all.

I next tired using `model.created_at` for the basis of the timestamp. Only one problem, that returns nil for the first version since it hasn't been put in the database yet.

After some further thinking I decided to try the following in my pictures controller.

```
def create
  if params[:picture] and params[:picture][:image]
    params[:picture][:image].original_filename = "#{(Time.now.to_i.to_s + Time.now.usec.to_s).ljust(16, '0')}#{File.extname(params[:picture][:image].original_filename)}"
  end
  ...
```

This overrides the original_filename property before Carrierwave even gets to it making it be a timestamp. It does exactly what I want. The original version of the file ends up with a name like 1312332906940106.jpg and the thumbnail version (or any other version) ends up with a name like thumb_1312332906940106.jpg.

But, this seems like an awful hack. This should be part of the model, or better yet part of the uploader mounted onto the model.

So, my question is, is there a better way to achieve this? Did I miss something crucial with Carrierwave that makes this easy? Is there a not so obvious but cleaner way of going about this? Working code is good, but working code that doesn't smell bad is better.

Comment: Glad to see someone else approves of putting all images in one big happy folder. I turned away from Paperclip because of its subdirectory nonsense. A unique filename is all you need. A computer doesn't need directories to be organised, they're very good at finding things.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do something like this in your `uploader` file, and it will also work for versioned files (i.e. if you have one image and then create 3 other thumbnail versions of the same file, they will all have the same name, just with size info appended onto the name):

```
  # Set the filename for versioned files
  def filename
    random_token = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{model.id.to_s}").first(20)
    ivar = "@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"    
    token = model.instance_variable_get(ivar)
    token ||= model.instance_variable_set(ivar, random_token)
    "#{model.id}_#{token}.jpg" if original_filename
  end
```

This will create a filename like this for example: `76_a9snx8b81js8kx81kx92.jpg` where 76 is the model's id and the other bit is a random SHA hex.

Comment: WOAH. You just made my week! This works flawlessly. I modified what you had a tiny bit to just make it be a timestamp using the format I was using already (because it pleases me aesthetically). But this does EXACTLY what I needed and in a very easy to understand and elegant Ruby sort of way in a place that makes sense. This really really REALLY should be in the Carrierwave readme. I cannot be the only person using this otherwise fantastic gem who has nearly pulled out their hair trying to figure this seemingly trivial task out.

Comment: FYI.. it appears it was already in the CarrierWave Wiki :)  https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files

Comment: This code will break though, because filename can't use model.id, since it isn't set until the resource is created.

Comment: I have been burnt by using `model.id` in filenames. Do not use it. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/carrierwave/5yiZmAPfMPk I believe the carrierwave generator does include an advice now to avoid `model.id` or `version.name`

Answer (score 4):

Check also the solution from carrierwave wiki available now https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-timestamp-in-file-names

You can include a timestamp in filenames overriding the filename as you can read in Carrierwave docs:

```
 class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
     def filename
       @name ||= "#{timestamp}-#{super}" if original_filename.present? and 
       super.present?
    end

   def timestamp
     var = :"@#{mounted_as}_timestamp"
     model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, Time.now.to_i)
   end
 end
```

Don't forget to memorize the result in an instance variable or you might get different timestamps written to the database and the file store.

Comment: Much better - this is exactly what we need in an answer. Well done, and thanks for editing it to include example code and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the same as described in [the official documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-timestamp-in-file-names)

But it always returns `original_filename` as `nil`. So just change it to instance variable as `@original_filename.present?`

Comment: did you mean `.present?` , not present**a**?